# Как получить объект при нажатии на него

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть функции нажатия на textBox'ы:

```
private void TextBox1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
      TextBox1.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
      TextBox1.IsEnabled = false;
      TextBox1.Text = "Press keys combinations";
}

private void TextBox2_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
      TextBox2.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
      TextBox2.IsEnabled = false;
      TextBox2.Text = "Press keys combinations";
}
```

Но тут происходит дублирование кода, что не есть хорошо. Можно ли избавиться от этого дублирования?

Как сделать одну функцию на оба объекта интерфейса? Представляю себе что-то вроде этого:

```
private void TextBox1and2_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
      TextBox tb = e.GetObject();
      tb.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
      tb.IsEnabled = false;
      tb.Text = "Press keys combinations";
}
```

Comment: TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

Comment: При присваивании каких-либо атрибутов к tb возникает ошибки.

Comment: Какие ошибки? Вы заменили `TextBox tb = e.GetObject();` на `TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;`?

Comment: @Almost  ну так укажите ошибку. Здесь ведь нет гадалок. А способ многократно использованный.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Когда присваиваю tb.Text = "text";

Так же не находит поля tb.BorderBrush и tb.IsEnabled, "'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'BorderBrush' and no extension method 'BorderBrush' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Проверьте тип в XAML <TextBox PreviewMouseDown="TextBox1and2_PreviewMouseDown"/> и using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev проблема была в том, что в проекте использовался класс System.Windows.Forms для создания иконки программы в трее, соответственно использовался System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, который отличается от wpf. Спасибо за решение проблемы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox1and2_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            tb.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
            tb.IsEnabled = false;
            tb.Text = "Press keys combinations";
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <TextBox PreviewMouseDown="TextBox1and2_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

Comment: А почему `as`, а не честный каст `(TextBox)sender`? Если вы ожидаете, что sender может быть другого типа, вы вылетите с NullReferenceException. Если вы не ожидаете другого типа, то «уверенный» каст семантичнее.

Comment: @VladD потому, что это мин. правка кода из вопроса. А по-хорошему надо еще if (tb==null) return .